# Context Param Values in web.xml get ignored

Tags: java, spring, servlets

I was always wondering why no primefaces theme gets applied and could never fix it. Today I found out that when I add a Bean "ServletContextInitializer" to my Application with the same stuff like in the `web.xml` it works. I read something that `app.properties` maybe overrides the settings? I got a `application.properties` but just for the database and jpa/hibernate.

Application:

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan({ "de.develop.telefonbuch" })
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean<RewriteFilter> rewriteFilter() {
        FilterRegistrationBean<RewriteFilter> rwFilter = new FilterRegistrationBean<RewriteFilter>(new RewriteFilter());
        rwFilter.setDispatcherTypes(
                EnumSet.of(DispatcherType.FORWARD, DispatcherType.REQUEST, DispatcherType.ASYNC, DispatcherType.ERROR));
        rwFilter.addUrlPatterns("/*");
        return rwFilter;
    }

    @Bean
    public ServletContextInitializer servletContextCustomizer() {
        return new ServletContextInitializer() {
            @Override
            public void onStartup(ServletContext sc) throws ServletException {
                sc.setInitParameter(Constants.ContextParams.THEME, "afternoon");
                sc.setInitParameter(Constants.ContextParams.FONT_AWESOME, "false");
                sc.setInitParameter(ProjectStage.PROJECT_STAGE_PARAM_NAME, ProjectStage.Development.name());
            }
        };
    }

    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean<FacesServlet> servletRegistrationBean() {
        FacesServlet servlet = new FacesServlet();
        return new ServletRegistrationBean<FacesServlet>(servlet, "*.jsf");
    }
```

}

My web.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
        http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_2.xsd" version="3.1">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>
        <param-value>afterdark</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>primefaces.FONT_AWESOME</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
</web-app>
```

Comment: One obvious problem is that this is not a valid `web.xml`, so it's most likely being ignored. You are using the schema for `faces-config.xml` - that is not the correct one.

Comment: I also got a `faces-config.xml`. It looks absolutely similiar to this example what was my beginning: https://dzone.com/articles/developing-jsf-applications-with-spring-boot. Can you tell me what's exactly wrong? The `web.xml` is also from this page

Comment: A web.xml declaration for servlet 3.1 has the schema, `xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
 http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"`. You can get more information here, https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/jsc/xml/ns/javaee/index.html

Comment: @AdamWaldenberg I changed it now but there is no improvement. Just the `xsi:schemaLocation` is different now. Still something seems to be wrong